# Добавление картинки на яндекс.карты

Tags: css, яндекс-карты

Я начинающий программист, пишу свой первый сайт. Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
не могу добавить картинку на карту так,чтобы при наведении она исчезала.
Выглядеть должно примерно [как на скриншоте.](https://vk.cc/8jlpkK)

Comment: Ваш скрин не совсем совпадает с вашим вопросом. Если по наведению хотете чтоб исчезало что-то, псевдоклассы юзайте как вариант.

Answer (score 1):

В лэнде:

```
<!-- iframe карты -->
<iframe>
    <div class="after_map"></div>
</iframe>
```

И в стиле

```
iframe{
    position: relative; // Или absolute или fixed
}

iframe .after_map{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(адрес/вашего/изображения);
}
```

Указывать тип позиционирования необходимо, потому что дочерний элемент за % берёт размер ближайшего предка с нестандартным позиционированием

Так же, чтобы изображение исчезало (jquery):

```
$('iframe').('hover', function(e){
    $(this).children('.after_map').fadeOut();
}, function(e){
    $(this).children('.after_map').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Если текст небольшой, можно использовать псевдоэлемент для элемента карты. и скрывать его при наведении.

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
  margin:0;
}
#map{
  height:200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,yellow,orange);
  position:relative;
}
#map:before{
  content:'text';
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events:none;
  background-color:rgba(100,100,100,.7);
  transition:all .2s ease;
  font:normal 900 70px/1 sans-serif;
  color:#fff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
#map:hover:before{
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```